# How to decode array of different data types?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I need to decode a JSON:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    foo()
  }
  
  struct MOCK: Codable {
    var array = [AnyClass]()
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case array = "arr"
        }
  }
  
  func foo() {
    let MOCK_JSON = """
      {
        "arr" : [
            0,"my_str1",
            90,"my_str2"
        ]
      }
"""
    
    do {
      let data: Data = MOCK_JSON.data(using: .utf8)!
      let manifest = try JSONDecoder.init().decode(MOCK.self, from: data)
      
      print("\(manifest)")
      
      
    } catch let error {
      print("ERROR:", error)
    }
  }
```

Here I use a mock JSON, but a real structure I work with looks the same

The error I get is

> Type 'ViewController.MOCK' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

How to decode the JSON correctly?

**UPD**

According to the @vadian comment I tried to use `unKeyedContainer` like this

```
  struct MOCK: Decodable {
    let array: [Any]
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
      var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
      array = try container.decode([Any].self)
    }
  }
```

But still I get an error in the last line

> No exact matches in call to instance method 'decode'

Comment: Use https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: @Cy-4AH it is not obvious what did you mean? In your example, you decode an array of strings in my example (actually it is a question) I am trying to decode an array of different types...

Comment: `Any` is not supported in `Codable`, nor `AnyObject` nor `AnyClass`. You array is regular and alternating `Int` and `String`, so use an `unKeyedContainer` and a loop.

Comment: You can look for "Any Codable", "AnyCodable" or "Generic" + Swift and there should be some ideas...

Comment: @vadian added an update to my question

Comment: just put you json and use generated code. I doesn't provided any examples

Comment: You array property is stil declared using Any, check the answer by @vadian again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any` is not supported in `Codable`, nor `AnyObject` nor `AnyClass`

A possible solution is an `unkeyedContainer` and an enum with associated values

```
let mockJSON =
    """
    {
        "arr" : [
            0,"my_str1",
            90,"my_str2"
        ]
    }
    """

enum MockType {
    case int(Int), string(String)
}

struct Mock: Decodable {
    
    var values = [MockType]()
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            do {
                let intValue = try container.decode(Int.self)
                values.append(.int(intValue))
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
                let stringValue = try container.decode(String.self)
                values.append(.string(stringValue))
            }
        }
    }
}

let data = Data(mockJSON.utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let result = try decoder.decode([String:Mock].self, from: data)
    print(result["arr"]!.values)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```